# How do I dismiss an ORKTaskViewController and present a view controller of my choice?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, researchkit

I've spent 24 hours trying to find a solution for this issue. When a user hits register on my app they will have to answer a series of survey questions (which I created using an ORKorderedtask (research kit)). Once the survey is completed I'd like the home page to be presented, however when I test the app and finish the survey it goes straight back to the register page. here's my code:

**1.presenting the ordered task view controller;**

```
let registrationTaskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task:  registrationSurvey, taskRun: nil)
registrationTaskViewController.delegate = self
self.present(registrationTaskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**2. Dismissing the task view controller(this doesn't work);**

```
func taskViewController(_ taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWith reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: Error?) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false) {
    let home = homePageViewController()
    self.present(home, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What ViewController is `self.dismiss(animated: false)` called from? It seems like you would want to dismiss your `ORKTaskViewController` rather than self, no?

Comment: The register page view controller.  How would I go about doing that? I'm extremely new to Swift building my app from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all the ViewControllers in your stack, I'd suggest not dismissing your register page view controller. Instead present your `HomePageViewController` on top of your Register screen. Just change your delegate method to this:

```
func taskViewController(_ taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWith reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: Error?) {
    let home = homePageViewController()
    self.present(home, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Or you could even present your `HomePageViewController` in the completion block after you prsent your ORKTaskViewController. The benefit of this approach would be that when the user dismisses the survey, they will see the `HomePageViewController` immediately:

```
let registrationTaskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task:  registrationSurvey, taskRun: nil)
registrationTaskViewController.delegate = self
self.present(registrationTaskViewController, animated: true, completion: {
    let home = homePageViewController()
    self.present(home, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

A couple more points:

• Classes should begin with capital letters (i.e. HomePageViewController). It's a convention that every single experienced developer uses, and Apple even recommends.

• Ultimately, I would suggest using a Navigation Controller to handle these transitions. With Nav Controllers you can achieve a much better 'flow' using push segues. It just feels better.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions are working for me, so frustrating but thank you for your help! I'll take your points onboard, I'm going to take a step back and do a little more research on concepts such as 'Nav controllers' like you suggest and hopefully I can eventually overcome this issue and learn. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hmmm, ok. It might help if you update your question to include more of your code. Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: Yes I am for the register/ homepage view controllers but not for the ORKTaskViewController if that makes sense?